# Using `git init` always create 'git bare repo' with the same name repo in the same directory

Tags: git

Using `git init`  always create 'git bare repo'  with the same name repo, call it 'A', in the same directory (created in this directory no matter where I use `git init`)

If is deleted repo 'A,' and do `git init` again, The (deleted) repo A **will be created again in the same directory** (as mention above). If I do 'git init' for the second time, I get the following error **as if my current folder has .git of repo A in it.**

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in path/to/repo/A
```

When repo 'A' is created, it will be in, i believe, unborn or unbound state which means there is no branch, branch will be created on the first commit.

Also, git log, git status, everything about gits states belongs to this repo 'A.'

I can use git clone, but git status, log, commit will still be shown **as if it is in repo 'A' git directory.**

git pull, push, commit belong to repo 'A' git directory

I stop using git on my local computer for awhile because I encounter this problem, but now I need to use it and have no other choice.

I tried to reinstall git. There is no help.

It is difficult for me to investigate this problem because I don't really understand how git init works internally.

My Questions here are as followed

1. How does git init work internally? In which case could my problem occurs?
2. How can I fix this problem? by fixing i mean, I just want to use git init, the way it is mean to be used.

Edit:

I have no clue why I put -- in front. I fixed it. Thank you pointing that out.it is just syntax. Detail of the problem is still correct.

Comment: `git --init` is not valid, do you mean `git init` ?

Comment: neither `--log` or `--status` are valid git commands. Which tool are you using? Looks like a custom script. Check what it does. Correct git command is `git init` or `git init --bare` for bare repositories.

Comment: A ["bare repo" has a specific meaning](https://mijingo.com/blog/what-is-a-bare-git-repository); instead of putting the repository files into a `.git` directory they're put in the current directory. So instead of `path/to/repo/A/.git/HEAD` you'd have `path/to/repo/A/HEAD`. Is this happening? If not, if you have `path/to/repo/A/.git/HEAD`, then everything you've described is normal Git behavior. `Reinitialized existing Git repository in path/to/repo/A` is not an error, but an informational message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update based on latest edit

I think I understand what is going wrong here.  Somehow, you have set `GIT_DIR` in your environment.  Exactly how, I don't know—but you need to *stop doing that*.  Check your `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` files; check any system profiles that might set `GIT_DIR` in the environment when you log in.  If you use a POSIX shell, test the current value of `$GIT_DIR`:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/tmprepo1
$ echo $GIT_DIR
/tmp/tmprepo2
```

Use the `unset` command to un-set it:

```
$ unset GIT_DIR
$ echo $GIT_DIR

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo1/.git/
```

(these commands were run after getting set up with the reproducer below).

#### Here is a way to reproduce the problem:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ rm -rf tmprepo2                # make sure there is no /tmp/tmprepo2
$ mkdir tmprepo1                 # now make /tmp/tmprepo1...
$ cd tmprepo1                    # ...and enter it
$ GIT_DIR=/tmp/tmprepo2 git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo2/
$ ls -A
$ ls -AF /tmp/tmprepo2
branches/       description     hooks/          objects/
config          HEAD            info/           refs/
```

Note that Git created `/tmp/tmprepo2/.git`, not `/tmp/tmprepo1/.git`.

#### Why did Git do this odd thing?

Note that I did not just run `git init`.  I ran `GIT_DIR=/tmp/tmprepo2 git init`.  I could also run `git --git-dir=/tmp/tmprepo2 init`.  **The key is that I am telling Git, explicitly, that it should not use my *current* directory.**  Here, I do this with a command-line-flag—`--git=dir=/tmp/tmprepo2`—or the *environment variable* `$GIT_DIR`, by setting `GIT_DIR=...` before the command (using POSIX shell syntax).

I suspect you're not typing in `GIT_DIR=path git init`.  But the same thing happens if I *export* this variable earlier, and then leave it set:

```
$ export GIT_DIR=/tmp/tmprepo2
```

and then, at any later time, run:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo2/
```

Somehow, you have set `GIT_DIR` in your environment.

---

## Original (long) response

First, let's note that `git init` has two jobs:

- create a new repository, or
- verify a few things about an existing repository, and update any template (example) hooks from any updated system templates.

This second job is rarely useful, but is what `git init` is doing when it says:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in path/to/repo/A
```

This means that you do in fact have a Git repository in that (full) path.  **This is not an error.**  It's just a request that most people never actually use.

Next, let's distinguish between `git init --bare` and `git init`.  This is a little bit tricky because of the two-jobs thing.  But there's a relatively simple distinction:

- A regular (non-bare) repository is a repository with a *work-tree*.  The work-tree, also called the work tree or working tree or any number of similar names, is where you can see and work with your files.  A regular repository consists of several parts:

  - Your work-tree, as just noted.
  - Git's *index*.  The index is somewhat complicated, but a pretty good short description is that the index is where you build your *next* commit.
  - The repository proper.  This consists mainly of a few databases.  We'll see more in a moment.
- A *bare* repository is a repository with no work-tree.  With no work-tree, you cannot do any work in this repository.  There are a few things you can still do but the real point of such a repository is to live on a server, such as a hosting server like GitHub or GitLab or BitBucket, where no one *will* do any work directly.

  (For historical and compatibility reasons, a bare repository still has an index.  The index's purpose is, as we noted above, mainly to build the *next* commit, and also to help keep track of files in your work-tree, and without a work-tree this index in a bare repository is not particularly useful.  But it still has it.)

#### Making a non-bare repository

Let's start by making a new, empty directory `/tmp/tmprepo` and moving into it.  (I am doing all of this on a Unix/Linux-like system, in a POSIX shell similar to bash.)

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir tmprepo
$ cd tmprepo
$ pwd
/tmp/tmprepo
```

If I now run `git init` *without* `--bare`, Git says:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo/.git/
```

With a casual look, it seems like nothing has happened, but if I look more closely, telling my system to show *hidden* files (dot-files) as well, I see:

```
$ ls -AF
.git/
```

Git has created a `.git` directory, just as it says in the output.  This is a regular, i.e., non-bare, repository.  If I run `git init` again, without `--bare`, it says:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo/.git/
```

and indeed that's what it did: without touching any of the important files in `/tmp/tmprepo/.git/`, it made sure that any hook *template* files were updated from my current Git installation.  Since I didn't change versions of Git, there are no such updates.  In other words, this didn't really do anything at all.

We can, if we like, peek into this `.git` directory to see what a regular (non-bare) repository contains:

```
$ ls -F .git
branches/       description     hooks/          objects/
config          HEAD            info/           refs/
```

That's the *repository* part of this regular repository.  Note that there is a file named `config`, another file named `HEAD`, and sub-directories named `info/`, `hooks/`, `objects/`, and `refs/`.  In general, you won't interact directly with each of these things, but the presence of these various files and directories make it easy to recognize an internal Git directory.

The directory `/tmp/tmprepo/` itself is the *work-tree* for this repository.  This means we can create, edit, and destroy any file we like at will—as long as we keep our hands off the `.git` directory that holds the actual repository, anyway.

#### Making a bare repository

If I now run `git init --bare`, though, this happens:

```
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo/
```

Since this does not say *reinitialized*, it did indeed create a new, empty Git repository.  Let's take a look, using the `-a` or `-A` option to make sure we really see all files including the existing `.git` file:

```
$ ls -AF
.git/           config          HEAD            info/           refs/
branches/       description     hooks/          objects/
```

The `.git` (directory) that is here now is left over from the earlier `git init`.  This `git init --bare` made a *bare* repository whose path name is `/tmp/tmprepo`.  That is, it took the existing `/tmp/tmprepo` directory and put into it all the *same* kinds of files it put into the `.git` directory.  So we now have two repositories.

#### What if you do this in the other order?

Just to check, let's remove both of these repositories (there is nothing valuable in either one):

```
$ cd /tmp
$ rm -rf tmprepo
$ mkdir tmprepo
$ cd tmprepo
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo/
$ ls -A
branches        description     hooks           objects
config          HEAD            info            refs
```

So far, this looks the same.  We made a new empty repository in the `/tmp/tmprepo` directory.  There is no `.git` because last time that was the `tmp/tmprepo/.git/` directory for the non-bare repository.  Now:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmprepo/.git/
```

This did not say *reinitialized*, so once again it made a new *non-bare* repository.

#### Conclusion

It's quite possible to have both a *bare* and *non-bare* repository in what amount to the same directory.  This is not a good situation, because it no longer becomes obvious which repository Git should use in this case.

We can test out what Git actually does using `git rev-parse`.  The rev-parse command has a *lot* of options these days, including `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`.  Working in this `/tmp/tmprepo`, which is both a bare repo—in `/tmp/tmprepo` itself—and a non-bare repo in `/tmp/tmprepo/.git` with work-tree in `/tmp/tmprepo`, we find:

```
$ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
true
```

If we *remove* the non-bare repository part of this setup and try again, we find:

```
$ rm -rf .git
$ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
false
```

We're now down to having *just* a *bare* repository, so we're not inside a work-tree, as a bare repository has no work-tree.

Removing both:

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf tmprepo
```

lets us start over.

#### Your specific questions

> When repo 'A' is created, it will be in, i believe, unborn or unbound state which means there is no branch, branch will be created on the first commit.

The *repository itself* will have no commits in it.  A new empty repository has no commits.

A *branch name*, in any Git repository, refers to one (1) existing commit.  Since a new empty repository has no commits, no branch names can exist.

In spite of this, Git still claims that you are on some branch.  This is what is called an *unborn branch*.

> How does git init work internally? In which case could my problem occurs?

It is not clear, from what you have said so far, what your actual problem is.

> How can I fix this problem? by fixing i mean, I just want to use git init, the way it is mean to be used.

You probably want to run `git init` once, **without** `--bare`, to create the `.git` directory, in the top level directory of some tree that already is ready to be, or will become, your work-tree.  If you have some existing files in this directory, that's OK.

Having run `git init`, you will now have a `.git` directory.  The `git status` command should work and should tell you that there are no commits yet.

You can now `git add` each file that you wish to be in the first commit.  It's a pretty decent idea to make a first commit that consists only of a `README` file and/or some other descriptive elements, such as a `LICENSE` file, but what files you `git add` are up to you.  Using `git add` copies each added file into Git's index (which we mentioned above); the files that are in the index are the ones that will go into the first commit.  Then run `git commit` to make a snapshot of whatever is in your index at this time.  This new snapshot will be the first (and now only) commit in the repository.

Once you have made the first commit, the initial branch name—usually `master`—will spring into existence.  The index will continue to contain copies of (really, references to) the committed files.  Add more files, and/or change the work-tree files and `git add` any existing file to overwrite the index copy with an updated version, and `git commit` again to make a new snapshot.  The new snapshot—the *second* commit in your repository—will contain a frozen copy of all of the files that were in your index, and a link back to the first commit.  Git will update your current branch name, `master`, to remember the raw hash ID of the new commit.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Your answer confirms my understand of git. Though, it does not answer the question. ( sorry if I didn't state the problem clearly, the problem itself it quite strange so it is hard for me to word them). I attempted to rewrite my problem here again. So my problem occurs after I deleted working-tree and bare repo, "If is deleted repo 'A'  and do git init again, The (deleted) repo A will be recreated again in the directory where repo A was located (regardless of where my current directory is)."

Comment: @A-nakWannapaschaiyong: aha, I think I may understand what you're seeing. To make the problem properly clear, you should provide a problem-reproducer (see [mcve]) but I suspect you don't know how to reproduce the problem ... but I do, now, I think.

Comment: Your solution works for me perfectly. but I find it quite troublesome to always have to unset GIT_DIR everytime i open git bash in Window OS. so I ran "git config --list --show-origin" to show all contents in all of git's config files (it list contents of all config files locates anywhere in file system) However I don't see GIT_DIR set anywhere. How can I permanently delete GIT_DIR to be empty? Thanks again.

Comment: `$GIT_DIR` is an **environment variable**.  Environment variables are more general than Git. It is **not being set by Git** (in your particular case that is). Look at things that are non-Git that set it.

Comment: Solved! Thank you.